# Python SyntaxError invalid syntax Error While Repo Init

Tags: python, repo

When i run

```
sudo repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-18.1
```

I am getting error -

```
 File "/home/rahul/android/lineage/.repo/repo/main.py", line 79
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if i run above command without sudo, i am getting following error -

```
/snap/git-repo/18/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/rahul/android/lineage/.repo/repo/main.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am having python3 on my system.

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Why sudo the first time ? The second error is normal, your user cannot update root files. You need to delete or change ownership of the root files to your user.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't cause syntax errors. There must be more to this. What is the code actually getting executed? What is `repo`? How does it use Git? Have you tried running in verbose mode (see documentation) to find out more? That said, it's often wrong to use `sudo`. In other words: This might be a bug in `repo`, it could be faulty use on your side. I don't see a programming question though, so I'd be tempted to close this as off-topic.

Comment: `repo` itself uses Python; your setup is probably causing `repo` itself to use the wrong version *of* Python (as run by `sudo`).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check the version of repo by using the `repo --version` command on your terminal and try reinstalling the repo package? Maybe the issue with the version.

```
repo version v2.21
       (from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)
       (tracking refs/heads/stable)
       (Wed, 26 Jan 2022 16:46:03 +0000)
repo launcher version 2.21
       (from /usr/local/bin/repo)
       (currently at 2.21)
repo User-Agent git-repo/2.21 (Darwin) git/2.31.1 Python/3.10.2
git 2.31.1
git User-Agent git/2.31.1 (Darwin) git-repo/2.21
Python 3.10.2 (main, Feb  2 2022, 07:36:01) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]
OS Darwin 20.6.0 (Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jan 12 22:22:42 PST 2022; root:xnu-7195.141.19~2/RELEASE_X86_64)
CPU x86_64 (i386)
```

If on mac: try brew reinstall repo as it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my own system (Debian 10), the system-installed repo launcher (`apt install repo`) is designed for and requires python 2.  But when you init a repo, it downloads a newer version of itself from Google, and that version requires python 3, but it gets run by the python 2 environment and fails.

As a workaround, I've been downloading a newer version of `repo` from Google:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo-1 > ~/bin/repo
```

And then launch it with:

```
python3 ~/bin/repo init ...
```

See also: https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo

I would prefer a more streamlined solution, but until I upgrade my Linux distribution to a release that includes a Python3-based version of `repo`, I don't know of a better solution.